# Close encounter condition for Nbody code

Tags: c++, collision-detection, conditional-statements, collision, orbital-mechanics

I wrote a simple N-body code using a leapfrog algorithm. Now what I am trying to do is create a close encounter condition. I want the code to let me know whenever two particles come closer than a certain distance. This is what I came up with, it seems to me that it should work, but it doesn't. It's in c++:
In the code: num is the number of particles, r[num][3] is a global 2d array that holds the 3d position of each particle (x,y,z coords).
I am just writing the function check_collisions, which is executed in the main function under a time loop, which evolves the system. 
What I was trying to do is to store the distances between any given pair of particles, and compare them to some distance (in this case rad[i]+rad[j], where rad[num] is a global array of the radius of each particle). If the distance between 2 particles is less than  rad[i]+rad[j], then I want the variable dummy to increase. Then I want to do some stuff those particles, leaving the others intact. 
The problem is that dummy is still 0 no matter what. I independently check that 2 particles in one of my trials are actual close to each other for several timesteps, but the dummy variable keeps on zero.
Here is the fucntion

```
int check_collisions(int num, double dt) 
{ double rji[3]; double r2, dis; int dummy = 0;
   double rad_sum[num][num];  double coll_dis[num][num];
   for (int l = 0; l < num; l++)
    { for (int m = 0; m < num; m++)  
      { coll_dis[l][m] = 10000; rad_sum[l][m] = 0;} }

  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
   { for (int j = i+1; j < num; j++)  
     {  
      for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        { rji[k] = r[j][k] - r[i][k]; }  
      for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) 
        { r2 += rji[k] * rji[k];      }
      dis = sqrt(r2);
      coll_dis[i][j] = dis;
      rad_sum[i][j] = rad[i]+rad[j];
      }//end for j
   }//end for i

  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
  { for (int j = i+1; j < num; j++)
    {      
      if ( coll_dis[i][j] <= rad_sum[i][j] )
      {   dummy++;
      }

      if (dummy != 0)
       {    do {  some stuff involving dt
             }  while (coll_dis[i][j] <= rad_sum[i][j]);
       }

    }
   }
```

}

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. You're not initialising `r2`. Set it to zero before each distance calculation.

Comment: Compiler doesnt give me any erros; I initialized r2 and the others but it still wont work.